# How to upload an Excel document with multiple sheets on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, share

I would like to know how to upload an Excel document that has multiple sheets, meaning more than one sheet on sharepoint 2013? When mentioning the range, how must I pick up all the sheets?

Comment: i know that SharePoint 2013 has the import sreadsheet app which i have added but it can only pick up the first sheet. i want to include the other more sheets

Comment: I think SharePoint Stack Exchange might be a better place to ask this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to do that, as the Excel sheets will be having multiple META datas, please try to put on to one sheet and upload